# Python convert string to bytes without changing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte

i have a string for example:

```
a = '031000060002043DCCCCCD213B'
```

and i want to get a byte like:

```
b'\x03\x10\x00\x06\x00\x02\x04\x3D\xCC\xCC\xCD\x213B'
```

(last four characters i don't want to splite)

but like string `'3d'` and `'21'` have been converted always due to ascii to `b'='` and `b'!'`, what i don't want, how can solve it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That's *just how bytes are represented when you print them to the screen*, they are still bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bytes` objects provide a convenience method for this, `.fromhex`, so you can just use:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(a[:-4]) + a[-4:].encode()
b'\x03\x10\x00\x06\x00\x02\x04=\xcc\xcc\xcd213B'
```

Comment: but what i don't want is like in string convert '3d' to '=', what i want is to have directly b'\x3d'

Comment: @wenqingqiu those are **exactly equal**, i.e. `b'\x3d' == b'='` nothing is being "converted", python `bytes` objects simply use the printable ascii characters for bytes that fall within the printible ascii range in it's string representation (i.e. when printed).

Comment: then my problem is maybe something else, but is there any way i get `b'\x213b'`? or is `b'\x213b' == b'!3b'` ?

Comment: @wenqingqiu yes, you can try that for yourself, `b'\x213b' == b'!3b'` will evaluate to `True`